# Matlab Error: Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've been receiving a code error that "Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation" however all my beta matrixes and my h matrix are showing up in the workspace as 201x203 so they should be the same dimension. I think my error may be coming from a change of dimension that occurs momentarily before the "impermeable boundary conditions" are added back on in the second half of the loop. Is there a way I can rewrite this/ fix the incompatible size error? The codes equation/ goal followed closely to a Laplace Finite Difference.

```
% Defining beta values
i=2:ny1-1; 
j=2:nx1-1;

oldbeta1(i,j) = (deltay*(k(i,j)+k(i-1,j))/(2*deltax)); %units: mm^2
beta1 = padarray(oldbeta1,[1,1],0,'post');

oldbeta2(i,j) = (deltay*(k(i+1,j)+k(i,j))/(2*deltax)); %units: mm^2
beta2 = padarray(oldbeta2,[1,1],0,'post');

oldbeta3(i,j) = (deltax*(k(i,j-1)+k(i,j))/(2*deltay)); %units: mm^2
beta3 = padarray(oldbeta3,[1,1],0,'post');

oldbeta4(i,j) = (deltax*(k(i,j)+k(i,j+1))/(2*deltay)); %units: mm^2
beta4 = padarray(oldbeta4,[1,1],0,'post');

% Initial Pressure Conditions (Zero Matrix) and pressure boundary conditions
h = zeros([201 203]); %h is pressure head
h(1,:) = 0; %pressure at exit (atmospheric, mm)
h(ny1,:) = InletPressure; %pressure at entrance (mm)

% Calculating Pressure Head 
for it = 1:niter
    hn = h;
    h(i,j) = ((beta1.*hn(i-1,j))+(beta2.*hn(i+1,j))+(beta3.*hn(i,j-1))+(beta4.*hn(i,j+1))) / (beta1+beta2+beta3+beta4);
    % Impermeable Edge Boundary Conditions
    h(:,1) = h(:,2); 
    h(:,nx1) = h(:,nx1-1); 
    h(1,:) = 0; 
    h(ny1,:) = InletPressure;
end
```

Comment: Please define all variables and include full wording of error message including line number. Please create a [mre].

Comment: The problem seems to be at the four elementwise multiplications `.*` - the two operands don't have the same size.  For instance, `size(beta1) == [ny1, nx1]`
and `size(hn(i-1, j)) == [ny1-2, nx1-2]`

Comment: Besides what @Sardar said, you also need to copy-paste the full error message into your post. The error message gives a lot more information than what you've shared here, and that information is important. For example, it should say exactly where the error occurred. I don't want to be guessing at that. Please [edit] your post. Thanks!